# Reset Password Page Not Rendering Correctly When Accessing from Reset Email Link

Tags: node.js

Ok, so first off, this is my first post. I've searched high and low for a solution, but have found none. I have posted this first on Udemy, for the course I've taken, but no one has answered, so I'm reposting it here.

I have been trying very hard to figure out why the new-password page will not display correctly for me. The reset link works fine, and I can even reset the password on my new password page when I am sent there from the email link.

However, no matter what I do, I can't get it to display any styling. It only gives me basic html. The logic works fine, it's just the page that doesn't display correctly.

I know it isn't a path issue to the css folder either. If I simply render as another basic page without any token logic, such as replacing my index page with the new-password page, then it displays normally. I just don't know what I'm missing, or if there was some updates that I need to take into consideration.

I'm hoping someone sees this and can help me out. It's the only thing that doesn't work right, and it's very frustrating.

Just to be a little more clear, if I do something like below, and just replace or create a route, the page shows up correctly. It's the token logic I believe that is breaking the rendering, I just don't know how, since I don't get any errors.

Please let me know what code you may need to see, as I'm not sure what sections would be helpful, there are a lot of moving parts here. I will be happy to post whatever is needed.

```
  exports.getNewPassword = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("auth/new-password", {
    path: "/new-password",
    pageTitle: "Update Password",
  });
};
```

With the logic built-in and following the email reset link, the below will not render any styling, only the html.

```
exports.getNewPassword = (req, res) => {
  const token = req.params.token;
  User.findOne({
    resetToken: token,
    resetTokenExpiration: { $gt: Date.now() },
  })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        req.flash(
          "error",
          "That reset password link has already been used."
        );
        return res.redirect("/");
      }
      let message = req.flash("error");
      message.length > 0 ? (message = message[0]) : (message = null);
      res.render("auth/new-password", {
        path: "/new-password",
        pageTitle: "New Password",
        errorMessage: message,
        userId: user._id.toString(),
        passwordToken: token,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

I am using ejs for templating as well. As I said above, if I remove all token logic and just render the page as a normal view, it works fine.

```
<main>
        <% if (errorMessage) { %>
            <div class="user-message user-message--error"><%= errorMessage %></div>
        <% } %>
        <form class="login-form" action="/new-password" method="POST">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<%= userId %>">
            <input type="hidden" name="passwordToken" value="<%= passwordToken %>">
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Update Password</button>
        </form>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case anyone stumbles across this, the answer was pretty simple, though I'm not sure why in this one instance is was a problem. However, the solution was to add a forward slash in front of my path to the css location for the update password page.

Again, not sure why it needed it, seeing as all my other css and view pages were in the same folder structures and worked fine, but it apparently solved the issue. SMDH.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css" />
```